# Constructor being called for each created class

Tags: java, constructor

My question relates to using arrays of objects. For each object that i created then set to scanner input values fales to work. This is because the output is showing the values in the constructor for each created object. Every object called with the get function displays the same values. What I want to happen is each object have it's own values.

---

```
 public GuitarSpecifications() {

        this.guitarColor = "Red"; 
        this.numStrings = 6;
        this.guitarLength = 28.2;
        this.guitarManufacturer = "Gibson";
    }
```

The code above is showing my constructor I created. The purpose of this constructor is to set any variables values that are not already set by the  scanner.

```
//This code was tested and worked. Creating the instance of the objects
    public static void instanciateAll(GuitarSpecifications[] guitarSpecifications) {
        for (int i = 0; i < guitarSpecifications.length; i++) {
            if (guitarSpecifications.length != 0) {
                guitarSpecifications[i] = new GuitarSpecifications();
            } else {
                System.out.println("Array of objects not created");

            }
        }
    }
```

This code above is showing my objects being created.

```
//Setting the values of the instantiated objects
     public static void setAll(GuitarSpecifications[] guitarSpecifications, Scanner input) {

        for (int index = 0; index < guitarSpecifications.length; index++) {
            System.out.println("Enter guitar color: ");
            String gColor = input.next();
            guitarSpecifications[index].setGuitarColor(gColor);

            System.out.println("Enter guitar length: ");
            double gLength = input.nextDouble();
            guitarSpecifications[index].setGuitarLength(gLength);

            System.out.println("Enter number of strings on guitar: ");
            int gStrings = input.nextInt();
            guitarSpecifications[index].setNumStrings(gStrings);

            System.out.println("Enter guitar manufacturer: ");
            String gManufacturer = input.next();
            guitarSpecifications[index].setGuitarManufacturer(gManufacturer);

        }
        input.close();
  }
```

The code above is showing my setting of the values.

```
//Displays the values entered from user input from setAll function
    public static void displayAll(GuitarSpecifications[] guitarSpecifications) {

        for (int i = 0; i < guitarSpecifications.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(guitarSpecifications[i].getGuitarManufacturer());
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println(guitarSpecifications[i].getGuitarColor() + "\n");
            System.out.println(guitarSpecifications[i].getNumStrings() + "\n");
            System.out.println(guitarSpecifications[i].getGuitarLength() + "\n");

            System.out.println("**********************************************\n");

        }

    }
```

Lastly, my output with get function calls from the class GuitarSpecifications. This is shown in the above code.

```
run:
Enter guitar color: 
Black
Enter guitar length: 
87.4
Enter number of strings on guitar: 
7
Enter guitar manufacturer: 
Fender
```

The above code is actual input

```
Gibson

Red

6

28.2

**********************************************
```

The code above shows the output. This is of course not the desired output wanted. I only used one instantiated object. This output would repeat if i had 20 objects created.

---

Again the results I want is to show the proper output of each created class  using a scanner. I have looked at other questions within this form without luck. I also could be misunderstanding the answers to the questions.

Comment: What is your question? How does your current output deviate from your desired output? We can't read minds.

Comment: You need to find out the source of the bug. Did you accidentally make your variables static, does code actually fail to read/override the values. Examine your program in parts to see where things go wrong, or run it through a debugger and see what's going on.

Comment: Hey Thomas, as the others mentioned before your question is not really helping other people understand your problem. If I may suggest something, reading this might help you clear your thoughts and increase your chance of writing a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I have updated my question to help with readability. What i'm looking for is knowing why the constructor keeps outputting the same data for each created  object.

Comment: I think you need to run your application while using a debugger.

Comment: I'm working with the debugger now to find the issue.

Comment: I've run the debugger and found out  it is setting the values but the getter methods are not calling any of the values. The values are either null or zero depending on the data type.

Answer (score 0):

You're not done writing your constructors, and you should not be hardcoding value *binding* in the argument-less constructor. Create a fully-qualified constructor, and then call that with your hardcoded values (ideally as constants, of course) as a fall-through constructor:

```java
public GuitarSpecifications()
{
    // of course, these values are meaningless, there is no reason
    // for a "default" guitar to be a red Gibson, the only real default
    // would be the number of strings.
    this("Red", 6, 28.2, "Gibson");
}

public GuitarSpecifications(
  String color,
  int stringCount,
  float length,
  String manufacturer)
{
    this.guitarColor = color; 
    this.numStrings = stringCount;
    this.guitarLength = length;
    this.guitarManufacturer = manufacturer;
}
```

Now if you call `new GuitarSpecification()` it builds that rather useless hardcoded one, but you can also call it with real values you got from your scanner.

Comment: To understand what you are showing me is that you have created a parameterized   constructor. I can then use this constructor for my setters.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean with "I can use this constructor for my setters": that is not how those words work together. The constructor creates your instance, and setters can then set (either from null, or override) values on that instance.

Comment: I found your comment helpful.